# Again about encryption

Tags: system-installation, encryption

I would like to install Ubuntu 16.04 on my laptop with full-disk encryption. But I have not found good manual about LUKS, LVM, etc. All manuals are not finished or incomplete. Many cammands are given with no comments. So, how to install Ubuntu 16.04 with full-disk encryption except /boot? How to keep hybernate working?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

During the installation process you'll see a window like this:

[image]

Check off the second option, "Encrypt the new Ubuntu installation for security," and your disk will be fully encrypted.

Here's a snapshot of my hard disk, which uses Ubuntu's default LUKS encryption:

[image]

Comment: Will I able to create partitions as I want?

Comment: Yes, under "Something else," but if you only want /boot to be left unencrypted, that's done automatically since it can't be encrypted (unless you're using LibreBoot, which I assume you're not).

Comment: What partitions will create automatically, if I choose "Encrypt the new .....?"

Comment: I just edited my answer with a screenshot of my disk partitioning.

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot! One more: does it swap, root and home on the right side? And why it's "unlocked lock" pictogram?

Comment: Oh, thanks for reminding me. I did `sudo swapoff --all` during the live session prior to installation, so I actually have no swap partition (16gb ram on my machine). So I was wrong to say this is a "default" installation. But yes, swap would otherwise be on the right side (don't know about root and home, I've never done separate partitions for those). And it's unlocked because I'm currently using it.