# Is Disk Encryption Included in Ubuntu 16.04 ? Or do i have to use the Alternate Ubuntu 12.04.5?

Tags: system-installation, filesystem, encryption, disk

Is Disk Encryption Included in Ubuntu 16.04 ? Or do i have to use the Alternate Ubuntu 12.04.5 to get the option to encrypt the disk as well as the home folder when installing?

I really appreciate a prompt reply as i am soon going to install it, and i really want the newest version of Ubuntu, but i have tried to fully encrypt the disk at other ways than just with the installation "disk" but i never figured it out.

So i was really hoping for an Alternate iso file for Ubuntu 16.04 just as it was for Ubuntu 12.04 that also made it possible to choose Full Disk encryption when installing Ubuntu/Booting it up without OS..

Please try to answer and if it is an alternate Ubuntu 16(If it is not included in default) Please link me an url where to download, if possible, i cant find it on ubuntu.com (I only find Ubuntu 12.04 Alternate).

Again, Thank you for a prompt reply!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Again about encryption](http://askubuntu.com/questions/797193/again-about-encryption)

Answer (score 0):

The standard installer of 16.04 Desktop is also capable of setting up full disk encryption. Simply check **"Encrypt the new Ubuntu installation for security"** when you reach the installation wizard step depicted below.

[image]

Comment: thnx for reply! Really appreciate it! It was about time it was included. looking forward to trying this new release !

Comment: You beat me to it. @BjørnErik Also note, Ubuntu 16.04 has no alternate installers as was for 12.04 had http://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads

Comment: This has been there since at least 14.10, maybe longer.

Comment: Also, if this answer solved your problem, please consider accepting it by clicking the grey check button on its left. You should also take the [tour] to learn the basics about how this site works. Thanks and welcome to Ask Ubuntu.